# MySQL - please help fix a mistake in the query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, many-to-many relation:

- BOOKS

  ```
          CREATE TABLE `books` (
            `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            `condition` ENUM('mint', 'new', 'medium', 'poor', 'needs replacement'),
            `date_added` DATE 
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```
- AUTHORS

  ```
          CREATE TABLE `authors` (
            `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            `pseudonim` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            `year_of_birth` INT(4) NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```
- AUTHORS_BOOKS table:

  ```
         CREATE TABLE `authors_books` (
            `author_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            `book_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`, `book_id`),

          CONSTRAINT `fk1_authors_authors_id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`) 
          ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE, 

          CONSTRAINT `fk2_books_book_id` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`) 
          ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```

What I am trying to make is to fetch data containing the following info:

1. book id
2. book title,
3. author's name

My query does not return the relevant data, I probably have missed the correct join somewhere, but as I see, the biggest problem is in my understanding. I would appreciate if anyone could check the consequence of things to be done as I see it:

1. specify the exact columns I need in my view:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, a.name FROM books as b
```

2. join the pivoting table on book_id:

```
INNER JOIN authors_books as ab on b.id = ab.book_id
```

3. Since I need the names of the authors, I am making one more join to bring into the game the authors table:

```
INNER JOIN authors AS a ON ab.authors_id = a.id
```

So in the end I have the following query

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, a.name FROM books as b
INNER JOIN authors_books as ab on b.id = ab.book_id
INNER JOIN authors AS a ON ab.authors_id = a.id
```

that returns me an incomplete list of books skipping most of them. I can't get how does it happen. Where is the mistake I am making, what concept am I missing?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the query. Can you pls show us some sample data, the result you are getting and the result you are expecting.

Comment: Yeah - would need to see sample data.

Comment: Your codes look nice, Can you get your expected result with a single query? Can you show us samples.

Comment: @Shadow Omg, guys you are right, I have a problem with one of my seeders. On the other side, in the second clause I should have used LEFT JOIN instead of inner

Comment: Your code is correct, the problem comes from your data, it will only return books for which it does find an author (using the authors_books pivot table). One way to fix this would be using left joins (to return `a.name = null` when no author is found). Also, if books can have multiple authors, which your tables can allow, the book will show up several times in your results.

Comment: @Shadow When I use LEFT JOIN in the second statement instead of INNER, I get +3 results. Why is it like that?

Comment: @Pepper I came to same solution in the end, and indeed it has proven to be the right one :) Please post your answer separately so that I can mark it as the correct one

Comment: You should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of both `INNER JOIN` in my opinion, in case either your pivot (authors_books) references an unknown author, or does not reference any author at all (no entries for a specific book)

Comment: @Pepper This is correct. Please post your answer separately.

Comment: If you insist :) Glad I could help!

Comment: glad that someone undestand me sometimes :D Have a good work.

Comment: My apologies to @BUcorp, I just realised `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` do exactly the same thing.... Could you please accept his answer instead, @Cheshire Katzzze?

Comment: @Pepper don't worry , it's enough for me that you are honest and competent with stack community. I don't like to read too much so usually i try to resume all information in short description. The explanation is the second step i think.

Comment: Looks like I can do it, so, done. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, a.name FROM books as b
LEFT OUTER JOIN authors_books as ab on b.id = ab.book_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN authors AS a ON ab.authors_id = a.i
```

because you are missing some rows i think you should use left outer join so you'll have the full result against the main table books

Comment: Outer join is not what I need here. Though indeed, I should have changed the second JOIN statement to LEFT

Comment: I understand but does the query extract all the missing rows you mention before? If so i'll reccomend you to just change a little this query adding where ab.book_id is not null for example.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @BUcorp, the main issue comes from missing rows.

To solve this you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of both your `INNER JOIN` to ensure all books are present in your results, even if they have no author or an unknown one (as in, with an ID not present in `authors`):

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, a.name FROM books as b
LEFT JOIN authors_books as ab on b.id = ab.book_id
LEFT JOIN authors AS a ON ab.authors_id = a.i
```

Finally, to avoid getting multiple entries in case a book has several authors (if that could happen in your situation), you could for example use `GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS authors` and `GROUP BY b.id`

Comment: hahaha thanks for mention